# Transit in Chennai airport

Tags: airport-transfer, maa

We arrive from London with BA into Chennai and transit to Colombo.
We only have hand luggage.

How long do we need for the connection and do we need a transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

Immigration could take around 30 minutes. Your flights are both international and should be in the same terminal. The gate will close around 45 minutes before departure.

From [this website:](https://www.indiaodysseytours.com/knows/india-transit-visa.html)

> If you meet all of the following conditions, you can transit through
>   India without visa. The conditions are:
>
> - Layover time is less than 24 hours as determined by scheduled arrival and departure times;
> - With confirmed plane tickets to a third country;
> - Staying in the specific Transit Area (means no clearing immigration, no re-checking your luggage).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply. Very helpful.